# Issue with unwrapping [String] when using image cache

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to rewrite my image cache to get away from using Alamofire, and in doing so I've run into an error. Previously, my image cache code was:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        // Check cache for image first
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        // Otherwise fire off a new download
        Alamofire.request(urlString)
            .responseImage { response in

                if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {
                    // image is here.
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And an example use is as follows:

`navBarCell.avatarImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(avatars[indexPath.row])`

Now I've rewritten the cache like so:

```
class ImageService {

    static let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

    static func downloadImage(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> (Void)) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else {return}
            var downloadedImage: UIImage?
            downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)

            if downloadedImage != nil {
                cache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(downloadedImage)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    static func getImage(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> (Void)) {

        if let image = cache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) {
            completion(image)
        } else {
            downloadImage(url: url, completion: completion)
        }
    }

}
```

And to use it in the same scenario as above:

```
        if let avatarImageUrlString = self.chatVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues as! [String], let imageUrl = URL(string: avatarImageUrlString) {
            ImageService.getImage(url: imageUrl, completion: { (image) -> (Void) in
                navBarCell.avatarImageView.image = image
            })
        }
```

And I'm getting the error `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'` on the `if let` statement.

I'm not sure how to handle this - I need the `[String]` array but if I'm understanding the error correctly it needs to be an optional instead of force unwrapping with `as! [String]`? I apologize if its a newbie question but I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks for any guidance!

EDIT:

I've tried putting the `let avatarImageUrlString....` outside of the `if let`:

```
        let avatarImageUrlString = self.chatVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues as! [String]

        if let imageUrl = URL(string: avatarImageUrlString) {
            ImageService.getImage(url: imageUrl, completion: { (image) -> (Void) in
                navBarCell.avatarImageView.image = image
            })
        }
```

But get the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'` on the `if let` line.

I've also tried removing the `!` and I get the error `'[Any]?' is not convertible to '[String]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?` with the fix recommendation of putting the `!` back in: `Replace 'as' with 'as!'`

EDIT 2:

```
        if let avatarImageUrlString = self.chatVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues as? [String], let imageUrl = URL(string: avatarImageUrlString[0]) {
            ImageService.getImage(url: imageUrl, completion: { (image) -> (Void) in
                navBarCell.avatarImageView.image = image
            })
        }
```

EDIT 3:

```
        let avatars = self.chatVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues[indexPath.row] as? [String]

        if let avatarImageUrlString = avatars, let imageUrl = URL(string: avatarImageUrlString[0]) {
            ImageService.getImage(url: imageUrl, completion: { (image) -> (Void) in
                navBarCell.avatarImageView.image = image
            })
        }
```

Comment: Never use `!` and `if let` (or `guard let`) on the same line of code.

Comment: I've tried a few solutions and added them in an edit at the bottom of my post

Comment: Just remove the `!` from the `if let` line and you are done.

Comment: @rmaddy check my edit, I tried that

Comment: Sorry I meant change the `!` to `?`.

Comment: Doing so results in the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: You see that new error once you fix the first error. `avatarImageUrlString` is an array of string. You can't create a `URL` from an array.

Comment: I've tried changing `as! [String]` to `as? String` and the error goes away but the avatar images don't show up in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually force-unwrapping `allValues` as `[String]` so then there is nothing to downcast. Also change type from array of strings to single string

So instead of this in optional-binding

```
as! [String]
```

use this

```
as? String
```

So...

```
if let avatarImageUrlString = self.chatVC?.avatarDictionary.allValues[indexPath.row] as? String, let imageUrl = URL(string: avatarImageUrlString) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'`

Comment: Saw your edit - don't I need the array though, as it's lots of values instead of just a single string. Or does `allValues` take care of that? Either way I tried it and the error goes away, but the avatar images don't show up in the app.

Comment: Check the Edit 2 at the bottom of my post - doing this only gets the first avatar image. I.e. in a collection view of avatars, the first avatar appears in all of them.

Comment: @KingTim yes you have to get certain index from somewhere in your code and then use it instead of `0`

Comment: I made an Edit 3, where I used `indexPath.row` in `cellForItemAt`... sorry to press on as I'm fairly new but I still don't understand what I'd put in the subscript.

Comment: This seems to work (after removing the `?` after `allValues`). What a relief. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KingTim yes you're right. In your case you don't need it